# hibernate one to many annotation Invalid column name

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 2 tables: Persons and Accounts(one to many relationship).

In my Person class I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private boolean admin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Account> accounts;

    public Person(String name, String username, String password, String country, boolean admin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public Person(){ }

    //getters and setters
}
```

In my Account class I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name="accountId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int accountId;
    private int balance;
    private String currency;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Person person;

    public Account(int balance, String currency) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    private Account(){ }

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using SQL server and the tables are created with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE persons(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    username nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    password nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    country nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    admin bit NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE accounts(
    accountId int IDENTITY(10000,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    balance int NOT NULL,
    currency nvarchar(5) NOT NULL,
    userId int NOT NULL foreign key references persons(id)
);
```

In my controller I'm saving a person and it works, then when trying to save 2 accounts of that person I get the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'id'.` The code:

```
    Person person = new Person("Maurice","vvvvv","ccccc", "France", true);
    this.personService.addPerson(person);
    Account account1 = new Account(1000, "eur");
    Account account2 = new Account(700, "gbp");
    account1.setPerson(person);
    account2.setPerson(person);
    this.accountService.addAccount(account1);
    this.accountService.addAccount(account2);
```

It's not the first time when I'm using a one-to-many relationship but I haven't encountered this error before.

The complete stacktrace:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
>   path [/BankingApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   execute statement] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: Invalid
>   column name 'id'.     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
>     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
>     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)    at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at com.haynes.dao.AccountDAOImpl.addAccount(AccountDAOImpl.java:26)
>     at
>   com.haynes.services.AccountServiceImpl.addAccount(AccountServiceImpl.java:21)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.addAccount(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.haynes.controllers.Controller.addPerson(Controller.java:47)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you check case sensitivity of the column? The exception indicates 'Id' with uppercase'I' whereas your code declares it as lowercase.

Comment: I updated the error now. It's "id". Before I had "Id" because I changed @JoinColumn(name="id") to @JoinColumn(name="Id") to see if that's where I'm getting the error from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinColumn(name="id")` should be `@JoinColumn(name="userId")`

Because `userId` is used as a foreign key in Accounts Table

Comment: so ?? what's wrong with id ? it can be used too as foreign key

Comment: Have you looked at the DDL of Accounts Table? `userId int NOT NULL foreign key references persons(id)`

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks a lot @Rocherlee!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if id column field for Person.java or Account.java is stored as Id in your database, while in your entity you have named it as id.

Can you please share the Person.java class and a full stacktrace of the error and please also check your database to make sure the fields are correct

Thanks.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'id'.